# Livewire 3 #[Url] Attribute

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am creating a datatable that tracks multiple properties with the #[Url] attribute.

```
    #[Url]
    public string $search = '';

    #[Url]
    public array $sorts = [];

    #[Url]
    public int $perPage = 15;
```

When I modify any of these properties they are updated in the URL as expected. The issue is when I send a link to another user.

Let's use this URL for example:
`website.com/search=123&sorts[created_at]=asc&perPage=25`

When we hit enter it will set all (3) properties correctly but will remove everything except `?search=123` from the URL. Regardless of everything I have tried search always works and no other property will work with `#[Url]` attribute.

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could depend on how the properties are valued.

Try using `#[Url(except: '')]` instead of `#[Url]`, it should work.
[Here](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/url#excluding-certain-values) the documentation

Comment: How does this address OPs question?

Comment: This does work. It shouldn't be required as the values in the query string are different from the original property settings - but it does. Thank you.